# Show that the sequence defined as $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^3+70}{39}, x_0=4$ converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined as $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^3+70}{39}, x_0=4$ converge. I would like to have a feedback on my proof, please (not sure about 1 detail). My attempt is to prove the convergence by induction.

To show that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges, we must show that it is bounded and monotonic.

First of all, we show that $(x_n)$ is a decreasing sequence. Suppose $x_{n+1}<x_n$. The inequality is true for $n=1$ so we can suppose that it works up to a certain $n$. We show now that it holds for $n+1$, i.e $x_{n+2}<x_{n+1}$. Thus, by induction hypothesis we have that:

$x_{n+1}<x_n \iff x_{n+1}^3<x_n^3 \iff \frac{x_{n+1}^3+70}{39}<\frac{x_n^3+70}{39} \iff x_{n+2}<x_{n+1}$

so $x_{n+1}<x_n \forall n\ge0$ and the sequence $(x_n)$ is deacrising.

We show now that $(x_n)$ is bounded below by $2$. Suppose $2<x_n$. The inequality holds for $n=0$ so we can suppose that it works up to a certain $n$. the next step is to show that the inequality holds for $n+1$. By induction hypothesis we have

$2<x_n \iff 8<x_n^3 \iff 2=78/39<\frac{x_n^3+70}{39} \iff 2<x_{n+1}$ and so we proved that $2<x_n \ \forall n\ge0$.

Therefore $x_n$ is convergent and it's limit value is $2$ (We obtain it by solving an equation $l^3-39l+70=0$, where $l$ is $(x_n)$ limit as it goes to infinity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is right. But you need not have proved that the sequence is bounded below by $2$, since it is trivial by induction that this is a positive sequence, so $0$ is a lower bound.

Comment: Yes I'm agree with you! But, are we agree that it isn't wrong either to show that $(x_n)$ is  bounded below by $2$ to conclude then by equation solving that it's limit is $2$(equation has 3 different solutions)?

Comment: @archuser, I agree that what you did wasn't wrong, it was just unnecessary. Irrespective of the lower bound, if there exists a lower bound of a monotonic decreasing sequence, then it converges, and hence, we can apply $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}$ both sides of the recurrence to find an equation of $l$, solving which gives the limit.

Comment: @archuser, The other solutions of the equation can't be the limit, that we can say just by the positivity and monotonicity, since $-7$ is not non-negative, and $5>x_0=4$.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your feedback! Have a nice day